# NerdTree re-positions Vim Window

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am using gvim on Windows 7. I just installed NerdTree and observed something abnormal. 
Usually I have two application open side-by-side by dragging them the left and right border of screen, and then Windows will automatically adjust the width and positions for them.

So, I have vim and another application open side by side today, and needed to navigate the file system. So I did NERDTreeToggle and all the sudden, my nicely positioned vim jumped to a different position (The default one when starting vim).

I am wondering if there is anyway to prevent this from happening.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question: your "nicely position vim jumped to a different position." What does that mean? Could you perhaps post a picture of the problem?

Comment: In Windows 7, you can have two applications stand side-by-side. Each has 50% of screen width, and full screen height. So, I am putting the vim window on the right side, taking 50% of the screen. And when I triggered NerdTree, the window of vim moved to the left bottom side of the screen.

Comment: Oh, I see... That's very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused because due to the vertical split (of the NERDTree sidebar), Vim displayed a second scrollbar (on the left), and that causes the Vim window to increase its width, and that made it "break out" of your layout.

You can avoid that second scrollbar via

```
:set guioptions-=L
```